# How to remove EOL escape characters in batch output

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a Python script that loops through a directory of .bat files. For each file it runs its batch script and then compares the output to a saved file containing what the output of the file should be, to test if the .bat is correct. Right now I'm testing it, and I have this as a test file:

```
@echo off
echo Good morning world and all who inhabit it! :D
```

I then have the "solution" file as this:

```
Good morning world and all who inhabit it! :D
```

This is the code to check the files:

```
for _, _, files in os.walk(dir):
    for f in files:
        result = []
        fpath = os.path.join(jobs, os.path.basename(f))
        params = [fpath]
        result.append(subprocess.check_output([params]))

        expectedname = dir2 + os.path.basename(f) + ".test"
        expectedfile = open(expectedname, 'r')
        expected = []
        expected.append(expectedfile.read())
        print '\nEXPECTED: %s\nACTUAL:   %s' % (expected, result)

        if result == expected:
            print "\n%s is correct!\n" % (os.path.basename(f))
        else:
            print "\n%s gave incorrect output!\n" % (os.path.basename(f))
```

The problem is, when the .bat file runs and produces its output, it has "`\r\n`" added onto the end. I tried just working around it by putting the "`\r\n`" in the solution file too, but it changes it to "`\\r\\n`" when its read. How can I fix this?

Note: Apparently SO's code formatting highlights "and" by default, the presence of the word in the echo doesn't affect it's functionality at all. Just didn't want it to be confusing haha

Comment: Update: I found sort of a work-around by changing the expected.append line to `expected.append(expectedfile.read() + '\r\n')`, but I feel like that's _really_ sketchy in terms of actual correctness.

Comment: "I tried just working around it by putting the "\r\n" in the solution file too, but it changes it to "\r\n" when its read." Huh?

Comment: martineau: sorry about that, I changed it to what I meant to write, it changes it to `\\r\\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this in your batch:

```
@echo off
<nul set /p "=Good morning world and all who inhabit it! :D"
```

btw. I have no clue from python.

---

And my second suggestion with `tr` from [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
ECHO Good morning world and all who inhabit it! :D | tr -d \r
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however when I tried this it ended up crashing, it gave an error on the line where I call `subprocess.check_output()` and says "raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:/users/soft/testjobs/hello.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: @thnkwthprtls I added one more suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Endoro, that one's working pretty well :) It's still a little buggy with a few seemingly random output files in my test directory but it seems to work for a big majority of them, thanks!